# Roland TR-808 TO Roland Boutique JU-06

Tags: audio

Just to reinterate the last question as to using the 808 with the Ju-06. What kind of lead jacks would i use to connect them ? I take it, it would be a 1/4" stereo jack from 808 output to 3.5mm stereo jack to input of JU-06 ? Or mono jacks ? Slightly confused !!

Answer (score 0):

The 808 is mono, so just a regular TS 1/4" plug will then go to what I will assume is a mono, TS 3.5mm plug for the input of the JU-06.  If it sounds funky (comb-filtering) or no sound but works if you pull the 3.5mm out halfway then use a TRS 3.5mm (stereo).  There are premade 1/4" to 3.5mm readily available.  Too bad RadioShack doesn't exist anymore so you could string 5 adapters together!